# Network discovery using SNMP in JAVA

Tags: java, networking, ip, snmp, snmp4j

Is there any Java example/tutorial to manage IP address ranges and do a network discovery using SNMP in JAVA ?
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416190/network-discovery-with-snmp4j) but i am on Windows and it is not useful in my case.

PS : I can use ping and and thread programming but i am searching for something specific for the SNMP protocol.

Any help would be appreciated because i have been searching for a while with nothing found .

Comment: What exactly is it you want to discover?

Comment: i want to discover all the connected snmp devices on my network

Comment: You do realize they provide Nmap for Windows, right? Why reinvent the wheel?
http://nmap.org/download.html#windows

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache [Commons-Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/):

```
String[] addresses = 
       new SubnetUtils("192.168.0.0/16").getInfo().getAllAddresses();
```

Than you can perform a snmpget with SNMP4j (for example the classic SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0) and see if you get the description or null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something more conplex like to discover the topology of your network you will need the ability not only to do snmp gets but also snmpwalks. Since it might be not trivial to parse and handle all snmpwalk outputs you might need something like snmp2xml4j to walk, do a xml and then to transform it to something more useful. For example netTransformer has been using that approach to generate graphml files from the raw snmp data. Once you get the graphml it is easy to add your own visualization layer on top.